# Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist Eero

Tags: react-native

### Enviroment

React Native Environment Info:

#### System:

OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz

Memory: 40.32 MB / 8.00 GB

Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/sh

### Binaries:

Node: 10.10.0

Yarn: 1.9.4

npm: 6.4.1

Watchman: 4.9.0

### SDKs:

iOS SDK:

### Platforms:

iOS 12.0, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.0, watchOS 5.0

### IDEs:

Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4907809

Xcode: 10.0/10A255 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild

### npmPackages:

react: ^16.3.0 => 16.3.0

react-native: ^0.57.1 => 0.57.1

npmGlobalPackages:

create-react-native-app: 1.0.0

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

If i write:

`sudo react-native run-ios`

it says

> 03:43:31: Starting packager... 03:43:41: Starting simulator...

and its stucks here

and if i write firstly

`Talha-MacBook-Pro:TusTTS talhasalt$ sudo react-native eject`

then

`sudo react-native run-ios`

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think your xcode are running background on a project that can't be build successfully. Make sure you have opened error free project on xcode(the project can be anything). After doing that see the magic.I don't know why its happening but work for me.